# Is there any way to get the first element and count how many times it appear throughout the columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the first element throughout multiple column and count how many times the value appear.

```
A       B
1,2,3 23,4,5
2     54 
2     2
```

```
result
1  1
2  3
54 1
32 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series`, then [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with selecting first values by indexing, convert to integer if necessary and count by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), if necessary sorting last:

```
s = df.stack().str.split(',').str[0].astype(int).value_counts().sort_index()
print (s)
1     1
2     3
23    1
54    1
dtype: int64
```

If need 2 columns DataFrame:

```
df1 = (df.stack()
         .str.split(',')
         .str[0]
         .astype(int)
         .value_counts()
         .sort_index()
         .rename_axis('result')
         .reset_index(name='counts'))
print (df1)
   result  counts
0       1       1
1       2       3
2      23       1
3      54       1
```

Comment: what if the df have more than one column and I only want to use two of the columns A,B and ignore the rest.

Comment: @Cheng - then filter it by list - `s = df[['A','B']].stack().str.split(',').str[0].astype(int).value_counts().sort_index()`

Comment: ok another question is it possible to retrieve the element for usage. For example i want to get the value '3' at the count columns. I have tried using print (s[0])

Comment: @Cheng if this address your problem and resolve it , please consider upvote and accept :-)

Comment: @Cheng - yes, use [boolean indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071871) - e.g. by `df = df[df['count'] == 3]`

Comment: @jezrael glad I can help :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! @jezrael